# What do the abilities on the hud next to Squadmates represent?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Next to each of my active crew mates is a ability icon:

[image]

What do these represent? Is it necessary for me to manage which ability is listed here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The last ability used. It is generally the ability they will use when you hit the squad member's quick ability key (Q and E on PC by default), unless it is ineffective against the current target, in which case they will use a more appropriate one. If it is greyed out, the ability is cooling down after use. A white flash represents the ability has just cooled down, and a blue icon represents the ability being available.

Answer (score 4):

As near as I can tell, they represent the *last active ability* that you told your squad member to use.

Besides providing an 'at a glance' way of knowing what your companions cooldown status is, you can quickly activate these abilities by targetting an enemy and hitting <kbd>Q</kbd> or <kbd>E</kbd> on the PC. On the 360 and PS3, it's the left and right D-pad buttons.